# Sort Sql Profiler results

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I recently used a free sql profiler product from Anjlab that was great and allowed me to sort the trace results even while the trace is running.  The next time I tried to do this in the Sql Profiler that actually comes with Sql Server I didn't see a way to sort the trace results.  Am I missing something or does the profiler that comes with Sql Server just really not let you do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can when the trace is stopped go to `File -> Properties -> Events Selection -> Organise Columns` and set up "Grouping" by the desired sort column(s) and then select "Grouped View" rather than "Aggregated View" in the short cut menu to get the results displayed sorted.

Doesn't look as though the grouping columns are alterable in a running trace however as the buttons are greyed out.

Comment: Thanks... looks like I'll be using AnjLab mostly in the future for what I'm doing then because being able to sort the longest running queries to the top as they come in has been pretty darned handy for quickly isolating areas that need to be fine tuned.

Comment: @BrandonMoore - Not sure if you saw my edit. You can sort by duration but you need to set it up in advance rather than when the trace is running (Edit: But you can't control sort direction and it is all a bit primitive)

Comment: Ah, no I didn't.  My team lead seems to have an affinity for Sql Profiler so I will let him know that... I think I will probably continue using the AnjLab product though since I can sort by various columns at will while it's running.

Comment: thanks for the comment... it wasn't clear from your answer that you have to re-run the trace again AFTER setting up the grouping once the trace is stopped.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware of a way to sort SQL Profiler output while the trace is running.

You can set up "groups" before you start a trace that including some sorting, but they're a bit klunky.

What I usually do is to have SQL Profiler save the results in a table, and do my analysis from there, using T-SQL.